# How to get parent div coordinates position on mouse click of child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a minimap feature, I have two HTML elements and these can be image or div, so when a user clicks on an element it should give/translate the coordinates of another target element.

The clicked element size (w/h) will always be small and the position will be absolute. so far I am succeeded to get clicked element position but I am not able to translate these coordinates into the target element.

https://jsfiddle.net/shoaib_ijaz/n1hzuc9r/

```js
 $(".child").click(function(e) {

   var offset = $(this).offset();

   var left = e.pageX - offset.left;
   var top = e.pageY - offset.top;

   var circle = $("<div />", {
     class: 'circle'
   });

   $(circle).css({
     left: left,
     top: top
   });

   $(".parent").append(circle);
 });
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #898383;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}


.child {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #eff431;
}


.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     child
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- some times the child element can be outside the parent element -->
```

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the coordinates using ratio of parent/child widths and heights

```js
 $(".child").click(function(e) {

   var offset = $(this).offset();

   var ratioX = $(".parent").width() / $(this).width();
   var ratioY = $(".parent").height() / $(this).height();

   var left = (e.pageX - offset.left) * ratioX;
   var top = (e.pageY - offset.top) * ratioY;

   var circle = $("<div />", {
     class: 'circle'
   });

   $(circle).css({
     left: left,
     top: top
   });

   $(".parent").append(circle);
 });
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  background: #898383;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}


.child {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #eff431;
}


.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     child
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- some times the child element can be outside the parent element -->
```